# panda groupby agg and calculated function together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below contents in  csv file

```
key1    key2    Key3    key4    key5

Val1    A        51     'True'  25
Val1    A        50     'False' 25
Val1    A        49     'True'  25
Val1    A        48     'True'  25
Val2    A        47     'False' 25
Val2    A        46     'True'  25
Val2    A        45     'False' 25
Val2    A        44     'True'  25
Val2    A        43     'True'  25
```

output should be like

```
key1 key2 max_key5 total_key4 total_true_key4
Val1  A   51       4          3
Val2  A   47       5          3
```

I have to group by key1 and key2 then find the max of key5 and count of total rows of key4 and count of total true rows of key4

What I am trying

```
print(json_data.groupby(["key1","key2"]).agg(
        max_key5=('key5','max'),
        total_key4=('key4','count'),
        total_true_key4 = ("key4", lambda x: count(x == 'TRUE'))   
    ))
```

I also tried like belwo

```
print(json_data.groupby(["section","row"]).agg(
    max_key5=('key5','max'),
    total_skey4=('key4','count'),
    total_true_key4 = pd.NamedAgg(
         column="key4", 
         aggfunc=lambda x: (x == True))    
     ))
```

I am not getting total_true_key4 proper value

Any suggestion highly appreciated..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to count the number of `True`s in any array is to take the sum of that array (since they're typically based on the integer values 0 & 1; True == 1, and False == 0).

```py
out = (
    json_data.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
    .agg(
        maxkey5=('key5', 'max'), 
        total_key4=('key4', 'count'), 
        total_true_key4=('key4', 'sum')
    )
)

print(out)
           maxkey5  total_key4  total_true_key4
key1 key2                                      
Val1 A          25           4                3
Val2 A          25           5                3
```

---

### Counting specific value via precomputed vectorized operations (fast)

You can use the same logic to count any value. First check where the column equals that value and then sum the `True`'s. This will be a very highly performant solution because we're leveraging true vectorized operations.

```py
out = (
    json_data
    .assign(_key4=lambda df_: df_['key4'] == "'True'")
    .groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
    .agg(
        maxkey5=('key5', 'max'), 
        total_key4=('key4', 'count'), 
        total_true_key4=('_key4', 'sum')
    )
)

print(out)
           maxkey5  total_key4  total_true_key4
key1 key2                                      
Val1 A          25           4                3
Val2 A          25           5                3
```

---

### Counting via Python function (slower)

However if you need ease of readability, you always pass a function to your groupby.agg operation instead of relying on `'sum'`

```py
out = (
    json_data.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
    .agg(
        maxkey5=('key5', 'max'), 
        total_key4=('key4', 'count'), 
        total_true_key4=('key4', lambda s: (s == "'True'").sum())
    )
)

print(out)
           maxkey5  total_key4  total_true_key4
key1 key2                                      
Val1 A          25           4                3
Val2 A          25           5                3
```

Comment: Thanks for this... but how If we need to compare with any particular value

Comment: Also in my case the true or false is a string

Answer (score 0):

I would probably simply use the sum function:

```
print(json_data.groupby(["key1","key2"]).agg(
    max_key5=('key5','max'),
    total_key4=('key4','count'),
    total_true_key4 = ("key4", "sum")   
))
```

It counts the True values as 1 and the False values as 0.

EDIT FOLLOWING THE COMMENTS :

If you want it for any particular value, I would then suggest to do it in two step. First, aggregate your groupby as a list:

```
data = json_data.groupby(["key1","key2"]).agg(
    max_key5=('key5','max'),
    total_key4=('key4','count'),
    total_true_key4 = ("key4",  list)   
)
```

Then use the apply pandas function to count the occurences of the item you want for every row of your dataframe:

```
data["total_true_key4"] = data["total_true_key4"].apply(lambda x: x.count("True")
```

In case of any other item you want to count, replace the string "True" by your item.

Comment: Thanks for this... but how If we need to compare with any particular value

Comment: Also in my case the true or false is a string